# Cut multitype symbols from string

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have list:

```
for item in list:                                                                       
    if item.startswith('Proj') and item.split()[2].strip('"').rstrip('",') in MAIN_MODS:
    print 'Project ID: %s Project name: %s' % (item.split()[0], item.split()[2])
```

Which produce next result:

```
Project ID: Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") Project name: "UnityUI",
```

I want to remove `Project("{` and `"` from result.

First what I realized - is `split` methods:

```
print 'Project ID: %s Project name: %s' % (item.split()[0].lstrip('Project("{').rstrip('}")'), item.split()[2].strip('"').rstrip('",'))
```

Which give me desired:

```
Project ID: FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC Project name: UnityUI
```

But it's look awful... So I trying to find something more fine.

Second solution - is to use `re.sub()`, but - how can I remove both parts in one RE?:

```
print 'Project ID: %s Project name: %s' % (re.sub('(^Project\(\"\{)', '', item.split()[0]), re.sub('(^")', '', item.split()[2]))
```

This will remove only leading parts (`Project\(\"\{` and `"`):

```
Project ID: FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") Project name: UnityUI",
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
re.sub(r"Project\("{([^}]*)}"\)",r"\1",test_str)
```

You can use this.See demo.You can capture what you want and replace it removing the unwanted by `\1`

https://regex101.com/r/sJ9gM7/118#python

Comment: Thanks, that's it. Just small edit: `re.sub(r"Project\(\"{([^}]*)}\"\)", r"\1", item.split()[0])` - need to add \ before `"` inside.